# Non-SSL actions inside an SSL secured WCF SOAP Service

Tags: wcf, soap, wcf-security, wshttpbinding

I'm very confused by this.

I have a SOAP client, talking to a server somewhere. I'm using WCF with a wsHttpBinding to talk to it.

Inside my app.config, the endpoint address is set as

```
<endpoint address="https://something.example.com/someService"
```

Since this is an https address and I'm using a transport binding, everything is happy.

However, inside the provided WSDL for this service, some of the actions are specified like:

```
<soap:operation soapAction="http://something.example.com/someService/someAction" style="document" />
```

Note how the action does not use HTTPS. 
What is the deal with this? Can you mix and match transports inside one service? Won't this cause problems? How could you even talk to a service like this? wouldn't my client application have to use different endpoint configurations based on whether the action has HTTPS on it or not?